# Symlink a directory and automatically sync its content

Tags: sync, symbolic-link

Suppose I have a folder `foo` with the two content:

```
data1.txt
cfg.txt
```

Now I create a new symlink called `fo2` which points to directory `foo`:

```
cp -s -R /home/user123/foo /home/user123/fo2
```

It's working okay. But then, I try to made new files in `foo` folder, say `data2.txt`. When I opened `fo2` folder, it only contains a symlink to `data1.txt` and `cfg.txt` `data2.txt` doesn't exist.

How to make the content of `fo2` folder automatically synced with with `foo` so `data2.txt` automatically appears in `fo2`?

`ln -s` is not an option because I want the content of `cfg.txt` in `foo` and `fo2` folder to be different. If I use `copy -s -R`, later I just come inside `fo2` folder, delete `cfg.txt` symlink and recreate a real `cfg.txt` with different content.

Comment: Do you really want to symlink the **content** of the directory, or the directory itself? To me, it sounds like `ln -s  /home/user123/foo /home/user123/fo2` is what you want.

Comment: I want to symlink both. If I use ln -s and opened fo2 folder, it will have 1.txt and 2.txt of actual folder, while I want the content of 1.txt in foo and fo2 folder to be different (for example, configuration files). If I use cp -s -R, I can open fo2 folder, delete 1.txt symlink and recreate a new 1.txt with different content

Answer (score 0):

If the locations are both on the same filesystem, you should use hard links. Otherwise, you'll have to setup some sort of synchronization, but that will be extremely inefficient in comparison.